# Sum from multiple rows, data transformation with PL-SQL from excel file into DB Table

Tags: sql, xlsx

Im struggling to write logic that will importing data from excel file into application db with pl-sql procedure. Issue is when im trying to sum hours from multiple rows with different 'code' for same 'work_id' and put them inside db. When im doing it for 'work_id' with only one 'code' it's putting data correctly.

Transformation diagram is very simple, source is .xls and target is database

Source Excel is looking like this

| work_id | code | hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 736 | 10 |
| 1 | 54 | 5 |
| 1 | 55 | 4 |
| 1 | 57 | 9 |
| 2 | 736 | 10 |
| 2 | 54 | 8 |
| 2 | 55 | 7 |
| 2 | 57 | 9 |

```
BEGIN
DECLARE
--TABLE. means it's from .xls source file, after .column_name that im getting data from and assigning into variable 

V_WORK_ID  VARCHAR2(50) := :TABLE.work_id;  
V_HRS      VARCHAR2(50) := :TABLE.hours;  
V_CODE     VARCHAR2(50) := :TABLE.code;

-- Assign variables to tables i want data to go into db
 
V_ECP      T_KLT_UP_ZB_ROZL%ROWTYPE;
V_ECP_DET  T_KLT_UP_ZB_ROZL_DET%ROWTYPE;


CURSOR C IS
SELECT DET.*
FROM T_KLT_UP_ZB_ROZL_DET DET, T_KLT_UP_ZB_ROZL H
WHERE H.ZEW_ID_KLIENTA = V_WORK_ID
AND H.ID = DET.T_KLT_UP_ZB_ROZL_ID;

    C_COUNT NUMBER := 0;  -- Initialize a variable to count rows
    V_SUM_55 NUMBER := 0; --  keep track of the sums for '55' 
    V_SUM_57 NUMBER := 0; --  keep track of the sums for '57'

BEGIN
V_ECP.SYMBOL := 'PZL';
V_ECP.UTWORZYL := PA_SESSION;
V_ECP.ZEW_ID_KLIENTA := V_WORK_ID; -- Relation between data in .db and .xls file

    -- Check if there are rows in the cursor
    FOR R IN C
    LOOP
      C_COUNT := C_COUNT + 1;
      V_ECP_DET := R; -- Assign the cursor data to V_ECP_DET
    
      -- value of v_code '54'  '57'
      IF V_KOD = '54' THEN
        V_SUM_24 := TO_NUMBER(V_HRS, '99999.99');
      ELSIF V_KOD = '57' THEN
        V_SUM_26 := TO_NUMBER(V_HRS, '99999.99');
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    
    -- This part works great, its putting values from excel into db tables assigned columns
    IF C_COUNT > 0 THEN
      IF V_CODE = '736' THEN
        V_ECP_DET.GODZ_ZW_I_ZM := TO_NUMBER(V_HRS, '99999.99');
      ELSIF V_CODE = '54' THEN
        V_ECP_DET.GODZ_50_I_ZM := TO_NUMBER(V_HRS, '99999.99');
      ELSIF V_CODE = '55' THEN
        V_ECP_DET.GODZ_ZW_II_ZM := TO_NUMBER(V_HRS, '99999.99');
      ELSIF V_CODE = '57' THEN
        V_ECP_DET.GODZ_ZW_III_ZM := TO_NUMBER(V_HRS, '99999.99');
      END IF;
    
      -- sum value of 55 and 57...this part DONT WORK ;/
      V_ECP_DET.GODZ_100_I_ZM := V_SUM_55 + V_SUM_57;
    
      TRK_UP_ZB_ROZL.DATA_IMPORT(V_ECP, V_ECP_DET);
      COMMIT;
    END IF;

END;
END;
```